# PHP MySQL query variables not returning

Tags: php, mysql

I store my testimonials in a database table and would like them to be displayed on my website via this for loop:

```
<?php

$count = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM testimonials"));

for ($i = 1; $i <= intval($count['cnt']); $i++)
{
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testimonials WHERE id='{$i}'");
    ?>
    <li class="span4">
        <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-1">
            <section> 
                <a class="link-1" style="cursor:pointer;"><?php echo $sql['name'] ?></a>
                <p><?php echo $sql['text'] ?></p>
                <a href="http:// <?php echo $sql['product'] ?> /" class="link-1"><?php echo $sql['product'] ?></a>
            </section>
        </div>
    </li>

    <?php
}

?>
```

The issue is that the $sql variables product, name and text are not displaying. However the $count is getting the correct intval, so it knows there are entries.

It's also worth pointing out that the loop is working as I get the `<li>` `<div>` and `<section>` tags working, the only issue is the `<a>`'s and the `<p>` not getting the textual value from the `echo`

P.S. I know that `mysql_*` functions are depreciated however my php version 5.3 and they are only depreciated from 5.5 so they are ok for my website.

Comment: You already got answer, but... i would really solve this on another way. You can have too many queries in loop, and it could seriously affect performance...

Comment: explain how you would do it

Comment: the $sql query has to be done in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed to fetch second sql

add this line

```
   $result= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) ;
```

and then call your variables like that

```
 <?php echo $result['name'] ; ?>
 <?php echo $result['product'] ;?>
 <?php echo $result['product'] ; ?>
                              ^^-----dont forget `;` because you missed them also
```

Comment: I've tried this before and it gave me an error on the page. I will try again and post what is displayed on the page

Comment: Nevermind, it worked thanks a lot. When I get the change I will accept the answer.

Comment: I said about mysql_* in the question, please read all of it before saying about it.

Comment: Oh btw, when you do <?php ?> for 1 line, the ; is automatically added and it not needed